# Java Active Remote Compiler (JARC) - Not Bound exception

Tags: java, rmi

Recently, I needed a remote compilation on java, so, I found the `JARC`:

http://pointdefence.net/jarc/index.html

So, I execute the shell script that runs the `RMI` server, but when I run the shell script to compile the java client, it throws an exception like:

```
 java.rmi.NotBoundException: jarc.server.JavaCompilerActive1.0
```

So, I want compile a simple "hello world" program on a remote server, does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: just curious:  in what kind of circumstances would someone need to remotely compile a piece of java code, as opposed to do it within the JVM on which it runs?

Comment: So, android source compilation for more perfomance

Answer (score 1):

> java.rmi.NotBoundException: jarc.server.JavaCompilerActive1.0

The name specified is not bound in the Registry you looked up. Either:

1. Your client looked up the wrong Registry.
2. Your server bound to the wrong Registry.
3. Your server bound to the right Registry with a different name.